# DTF Custom Action reference in WiX not a valid WiX reference

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, dtf, wix3.5

I can build a managed custom action just fine using the DTF tools (I.E MakeSfxCA.exe) 

My post build event command line looks like this: 

`"%WIX%SDK\MakeSfxCA.exe" 


"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).CA.dll" 

 
"%WIX%SDK\x86\SfxCA.dll" 

 
"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" 


"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"`

But whenever I attempt to add a reference to the compiled dll I get an error stating something to the effect of

```
“make sure that the file is accessible and a valid WiX reference”
```

If i add the project as a ref using visual studio (2010 & 2008) my WiX Project compiles but does not use the dll. I receive this message when I attempt to run the msi

```
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. 
A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. 
Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
```

My wxs file looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/js3aejXw)

My OS is Windows 7 and I'm using .net 4.0 is that makes a difference
and I'm using the weekly build

```
http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.1721.0/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was with the compiled dll not being compiled for the correct type of environment. I.E. building a x64 version for a x86 installer. Feel free to comment if I need to clarify more.

Comment: I ended up using a vbscript custom action instead for simplicity sake

Comment: VBScript is possibly the worst option possible: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx :)

Comment: At the time I did read your article, I really did. However I also had a deadline and needed something that worked also my script was a pretty simple config script for IIS deployment.  (and didn't require me to learn C or C++ lol) Since then we ended up using the built in IIS facilities in wix. Thanks for the comment.